# An error happened while using swipper in flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

i use SliverList to hide the the swiper but it give me errors about the swiper's controller (I think ) that state Is not saved or something help me fix it and thanks a lot

the UI code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
import 'package:medixa_app/Routes/CategoryRoute.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeTabState createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {
  var names = [
    'INFO',
    'ABOUT',
    'EVO',
    'CONTACT US',
  ];

  var links = [
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1282308/pexels-photo-1282308.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/40568/medical-appointment-doctor-healthcare-40568.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/935869/pexels-photo-935869.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940',
  ];

  var swiperController;

  List<StackFit> stackList = [StackFit.expand, StackFit.loose];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    swiperController = SwiperControl(
      iconPrevious: null,
      iconNext: null,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(

              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: names.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) => new MenuItem(names[i], i),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    child: Swiper(
                      loop: false,
                      autoplay: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return Stack(
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
                          fit: StackFit.expand,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(
                              links[i],
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
                              child: Container(
                                constraints:
                                    BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.maxFinite),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Descreption: ${i}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: links.length,
                      pagination: new SwiperPagination(),
                      control: swiperController,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                addRepaintBoundaries: false
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, i) {
                return new Container(
                  height: 80.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.account_circle,
                          color: Colors.deepPurple[((i + 1) % 10) * 100],
                          size: 48.0,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text('Title: ${i + 1}'),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }, childCount: 20),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final int id;

  MenuItem(this.title, this.id);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 8.0,
          horizontal: 8.0,
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => new CategoryRoute(title, id)));
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Text(title),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error

> I/flutter ( 2601): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 2601): The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for SwiperController:
>   I/flutter ( 2601): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
>   I/flutter ( 2601): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a
>   I/flutter ( 2601): widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling
>   I/flutter ( 2601): inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
>   I/flutter ( 2601): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3233:9)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3242:6)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #2      Element.visitAncestorElements (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3329:12)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #3      Notification.dispatch (package:flutter/src/widgets/notification_listener.dart:59:12)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #4      ScrollActivity.dispatchScrollEndNotification (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_activity.dart:106:63)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #5      ScrollPosition.didEndScroll (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:639:14)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #6      ScrollPosition.beginActivity (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:608:9)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #7      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.beginActivity (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:117:11)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #8      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.goIdle (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:132:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #9      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.jumpTo (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:196:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #10     ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.animateTo (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:178:7)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #11     PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:119:21)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #12     _TransformerPageViewState.onChangeNotifier (package:transformer_page_view/transformer_page_view.dart:582:12)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #13     ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:161:21)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #14     IndexController.next (package:transformer_page_view/index_controller.dart:70:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #15     _SwiperTimerMixin._onTimer (package:flutter_swiper/src/swiper.dart:370:17)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #16     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #17     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): #18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
>   I/flutter ( 2601): The SwiperController sending notification was:
>   I/flutter ( 2601):   Instance of 'SwiperController'

the dependcy :

> flutter_swiper : ^1.1.4

thanks a lot

Comment: I had the same problem and I changed it to 1.1.2 then worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per checking, [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper) is the old version of [card_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper) plugin. The latest plugin is now compatible with null safety feature of Flutter, I recommend using the latest plugin as it is more stable. Regarding the replication of the error, the error you've posted is not showing when I'm using the latest plugin.

Here is a sample from the plugin itself:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Swiper(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Image.network(
            "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          );
        },
        itemCount: 3,
        pagination: SwiperPagination(),
        control: SwiperControl(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]